# How to supply tag helper attribute from model value

Tags: asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a tag helper that includes an attribute whose value is an enumeration:

```
public class MyElementTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public MyAttribute MyAttribute { get; set; }
}

public attribute MyAttribute { apple, banana, cherry }
```

This allows me to create an HTML `<my-element>` tag that takes a `my-attribute` attribute, like this:

```
<my-element my-attribute="apple">
```

My question is: Suppose my view model looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyAttribute MyAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to use the `MyAttribute` value **from the view model** as the value to the HTML attribute, kind of like this:

```
<my-element my-attribute="Model.MyAttribute">
```

More generally, is there a way to reference a variable as the attribute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answering my own question]

Simply introduce the C# variable with an "@" inside of the quote marks, like this:

```
<my-element my-attribute="@Model.MyAttribute">
```

(I posted the question because I was certain that this wouldn't work. I'm pretty sure I had tried this a few months ago and it didn't work. Either I'm loosing my mind - a distinct possibility - or this is new stuff added in the last several months.)